# How to use jQuery Lazy with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using [jQuery Lazy](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy) to load images in a page progressively. When the images are called with AJAX, they do do not load. Please, how to use this Plugin with AJAX?

I tried:

```
$(function() {
    $('.lazy').lazy({
      placeholder: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEALAPQAPzl5uLr9Nrl8e7...",
      effect: "fadeIn",
      effectTime: 2000,
      threshold: 0
    });
});
```

However it is not working. Some time back, when I had that challenge with Colorbox, the solution was to call for `body click`, like:

```
$("body").on("click", ".photos", function(event){
    $(".photos").colorbox({rel:'photos', transition:"fade"});
});
```

That made the trick to enable colorbox to work with an AJAX call - but with Lazy there is no `body click`, so even though I did:

```
$(function() {
    $('body .lazy').lazy({
      placeholder: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEALAPQAPzl5uLr9Nrl8e7...",
      effect: "fadeIn",
      effectTime: 2000,
      threshold: 0
    });
});
```

So, how to use jQuery Lazy with AJAX?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by 'when the images are *called* with AJAX' - are you calling the `.lazy` from an ajax method?  are you *adding* images via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please think about how jQuery (*and Lazy*) work. There is not kind of *auto detection* of new elements (*expect somebody builds it on its own*). So, if you load new elements via AJAX you need to tell jQuery/Lazy that there are new elements.

In case of Lazy, there are some [public functions](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy#instances-and-public-functions) you can use of an instance. In your case, you would need to use `addItems` and `update`.

With `addItems`, you can add new elements to an existing instance of Lazy. So the plugin knows that he has to handle these elements too. With `update`, you can force Lazy to do a single update of the current viewport, without using `scroll` or `resize` event.

So, that means, you have to slightly update your code:

```
var instance = $('.lazy').lazy({
    chainable: false, // tell lazy to return its own instance
    placeholder: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEALAPQAPzl5uLr9Nrl8e7...",
    effect: "fadeIn",
    effectTime: 2000,
    threshold: 0
});
```

Afterwards you need to use the two public functions, mentioned above, after the AJAX request got finished. I don't know how you load the new elements, but there might be a callback or something where you could execute these.

```
instance.addItems('.jquery-selector-for-new-items-only');
instance.update();
```

If you have the new elements already as jQuery object, you can use `addItems` with them too. So instead of a selector, just add the object:

```
instance.addItems($('.jquery-object'));
instance.update();
```

And that's it ...

Comment: Wow. I wish i could add several plus one to this. Thanks a lot. The following worked for me ```instance.addItems('.lazy');
instance.update();``` . If someone faces the same problem, just add that line to your script

Comment: Glad I could helped you! Just another hind: better use a more precise selector than `.lazy` in your 'addItems' call. Because with this selector, you will add all elements with the class `lazy` over and over again on each AJAX request. It would be better, if you have a decent selector, just selecting the _new_ elements. Lazy will try to take care, if you add the same items again, but the performance would be better, if you just just a _better_ selector, if possible. @ManOfGod